# Log the user who destroyed a record using 'before_destroy' callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I want to log the user who destroyed a record using `before_destroy` callback. But, I dont know how to pass arguments to `before_destroy`(and I am not sure if it is possible). Maybe I am dealing this in the wrong way. Any other perspective to do this will also do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a virtual attribute on the `Record` model called `destroyer` or something.

Then you can do whatever you want with that attribute in your `before_destroy` callback.

Comment: ok..got it..so I have to set it like `@record.destroyer = current_user`, right?..thanks :)